# how to query an array column in rails? with where condition?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays

i am having the following columns in my table `t.string :appr_status  , type: Array, default: []` and  `t.integer :employee_id` and my current query is

```
     @reg_req = AttendanceChangeRequest.where("employee_id IN (?)", emp_id_arr).to_a
```

where `emp_id_arr` is an array like `[1,2,3]`. and i want to change the above query to this.

```
    AttendanceChangeRequest.where('(employee_id IN = ? AND appr_status contain= ?) ', emp_id_arr , appr_array )
```

where appr_array = ["1_app","2_app", "3_appr","4_appr"] is this. i want to get all the records when any one of the employee id is present in the   passing array that is `emp_id_arr` and appr_status column should  contain  all values which are present in the passing array to the query (that is in `appr_array`) if one value is also not present then i dont want that record. how to write this query?

Answer (score 0):

u need to like

```
AttendanceChangeRequest.where("'1_app' = ANY (appr_status)")
```

This will work correctly.

Comment: in that case it will return the records which will contain only  "1_app ". but i want the records only when all the array elements of passing array (appr_status) is present then only i want to retrieve those records. for eg in that array column "2_app" is not present and the remaining all the passed values it is having. then i don t want to retrieve those record.

Comment: AttendanceChangeRequest.where("['1_app','2_app', '3_appr','4_appr'] = ANY (appr_status)")
is it working?

Comment: AttendanceChangeRequest.where("['1_app','2_app', '3_appr','4_appr'] = ANY (appr_status)") is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AttendanceChangeRequest.where(employee_id: emp_id_arr,appr_status: appr_array)
```

This is what you are looking?

Comment: i want  to get those records  where employee_id should  present in the employee array and appr_status column should must contain all the values that are present in the passed array(appr_array)  then only i want those records. but the above query is returning the records even if  one of the value is present in the passed array(appr_array).

Comment: i want  to get those records  where employee_id should  present in the employee array and appr_status column should must contain all the values that are present in the passed array(appr_array)  then only i want those records. but the above query is returning the records even if  one of the value is present in the passed array(appr_array).    lets say i am passing   appr_array = [1_app,2_app,3_app]  but the database column  "appr_status" contains only [1_app] . as it is not having the remaining 2 values (2_app,3_app) i donot want to get that record. but the above query  returns this record.

Comment: `attendance =  AttendanceChangeRequest.where(employee_id: emp_id_arr,appr_status: appr_array) if attendance.count ==  appr_array.count  @reg_req = attendance else @reg_req = [] end`

Answer (score 0):

AttendanceChangeRequest.where("array_to_string(appr_status, '||') ILIKE :name", name: "%your desire search able value here%")

This is what you are looking?
what this query ll do.

- this ll find the record from table where colum of appr_status having
  datatype  array contain your desire given value. For example
  appr_status col has array [1,2,3,4] user want to fatch record from
  appr_status col where each array of appr_status contain integer 3
  here 3 will be your desire given value you can put it via variable or
  hardcot